# how to customize my views-view-table.tpl.php?

Tags: views

i have a view table for property list and i want to customize the view source code to make it print specific label that i add from inside of view in the administration

the view source code :

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <?php foreach ($header as $field => $label): ?>
      <th <?php if ($header_classes[$field]) { print 'class="'. $header_classes[$field] . '" '; } ?> scope="col">
        <?php print $label; ?>
      </th>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

but this code print all fields labels even its empty!

output :[image]

the output that i need like this :

[image]

any suggestion to update the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use [field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle_name)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7.x)to get information about specific instance of a field. The label of the field is contained in the array returned from that function.

The general code :

`<?php
 $info = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle_name);
 print $info['label'];
    ?> :`

in my situation :

`<?php
 $info = field_info_instance('node','property_photo','property');
 print $info['label'];
    ?> :`

OR

by Using this Code :

```
<?php print $header['$field_name']; ?> :
```

in my situation :

```
    <?php print $header['property_photo']; ?> :
```

that's it .